# MySQL duplicated rows within a group based on selected columns

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, duplicates

Say I have a table a

```
id sequence card_tap time
1    1         61      1
1    2         62      10 
1    3          2      20
2    11        12       5
2    12        61       10
2    12        62       20
```

I want to find the duplicated `sequence` within each `id` group (id they exist), in this case

```
id sequence card_tap time
2    12        61       10
2    12        62       20
```

May I ask how to do that, preferably in a fast way as I have a large dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno how fast this *can* be, can't figure out any way to do this without aggregating on id/sequence.

> SELECT id, sequence, count(*) as n_rows
>
> FROM a
>
> GROUP BY id, sequence
>
> HAVING n_rows > 1

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: Oops, overlooked the non-uniqueness of id, fixed.

These would be my first instincts:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE (id, sequence) IN (
      SELECT id, sequence 
      FROM the_table 
      GROUP BY id, sequence 
      HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
   );
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table AS t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, sequence 
    FROM the_table 
    GROUP BY id, sequence 
    HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
) AS s USING (id, sequence)
;
```

Personally, I'd go with the JOIN first, in my experience they are better able to take advantage of indexes... if you had one on (id, sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Use `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.id, t.sequence) in (select t2.id, t2.sequence
                             from t t2
                             group by t2.id, t2.sequence
                             having count(*) > 1
                            );
```